How to override or ignore content-type request header in node.js
I have a node.js server which is being called with a content-type of application/json however the body it sends in is not json but raw text in the form of:
client_id=q9r71WPJtK5JWbkq7LAATEhQoXHQCJ9z&code_verifier=CiC6e0mZirQAwKkLvhiitiVuEvf2ZaFD7hsENkAhxyO&grant_type=authorization_code&code=TkdVtUfvtb4vKyJTRa9Z5F5G6_R8cwj6eIR6VGd0Tt0XX&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fuat.test.com.au

I've been playing for the call in postman and if I set it to application/json it displays
{}
If I set it to text/plain it displays the correct data as sent in.
I'm simulating an external vendors system and can't, in the near term, get a change the content-type.
Question:
is there anyway of forcing node to assume this is text not json and process as such.
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
 
// Without this middleware
app.use(express.text());
app.post('/oauth/token', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end();
})
 
app.listen(PORT, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log("Server listening on PORT", PORT);
});

example curl out of postman
curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/oauth/token' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data 'client_id=q9r71WPJtK5JWbkq7LAATEhQoXHQCJ9z&code_verifier=CiC6e0mZirQAwKkLvhiitiVuEvf2ZaFD7hsENkAhxyO&grant_type=authorization_code&code=TkdVtUfvtb4vKyJTRa9Z5F5G6_R8cwj6eIR6VGd0Tt0XX&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fuat.tab.com.au'


The main thing I've been trying is looking into ways of ignoring or overwriting the content-type in te request header

The text middleware has the option to set which media types determine if the request body should be parsed (by default it will only parse the request body if the content type is text/plain)
Add application/json to the middleware option types to make sure the request body is being parsed:
import express, { text } from "express";
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

// Without this middleware
app.use(text({ type: ["text/plain", "application/json"] }));
app.post("/oauth/token", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.end();
});

app.listen(PORT, function (err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log("Server listening on PORT", PORT);
});

It might not be "best practice" but it will do the trick in your case
